# CAKEphp Virtual field not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Because i have two price columns in my table (subscription_discount and subscription_price). I need to find a way to find the lowest of the two and use it. The problem is that this only has to occur when subscription_discount is lower then subscription_price and when subscription_discount is not 0.00.

This is my code to create the virtual field in my model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'end_price' => "IF(Abonnement.subscription_discount IS NOT NULL OR Abonnement.subscription_discount < Abonnement.subscription_price, Abonnement.subscription_price), Abonnement.subscription_discount)"
    );
```

Somehow this ends up in an error in my view:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),
>   `Abonnement`.`subscription_discount`)) AS `Abonnement__end_price` FROM
>   `cake' at line 1

I don't understand what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'end_price' => "IF(Abonnement.subscription_discount IS NOT NULL OR Abonnement.subscription_discount < Abonnement.subscription_price, Abonnement.subscription_price>>>**)**<<<, Abonnement.subscription_discount)"
    );
```

remove it